# GeoPandas and CRS: different units

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

I am trying to write a function that takes as input two files:

- A Shapefile of a region of interest,
- A CSV file containing columns with latitudes and longitudes for the stations of interest.

The output is simply a map with the region and points referring to these stations. I am using GeoPandas for this:

```
def map_stations(self, path_shp, path_csv):
    """
    Maps the stations starting from 
    CSV file containing columns with 
    latitudes and longitudes, and SHP file 
    for the region of interest.
    """

    crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

    map_ = gpd.read_file(path_shp)
    map_.crs = crs

    df = pd.read_csv(path_csv)
    geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]
    geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

    _, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 15))
    map_.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.5, color='grey')
    geo_df.plot(ax=ax, markersize=10, color='red', marker='o')
```

It's pretty straightforward. The problem is with the *scale* of the [Shapefile](http://www.istat.it/storage/cartografia/confini_amministrativi/generalizzati/Limiti01012018_g.zip) I am using. The values of latitude and longitude are on a *different scale* than the ones in my CSV [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7rp7lleggr1u1o/openaq_aq.csv?dl=0).

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Isn't setting the CRS enough?

Comment: Your shapefile has an epsg that is not 4326, but you're assigning it 4326. Just remove the "map_.crs=crs" line and I would expect your problem to go away. If you want them to both be in the same CRS, you can use the "to_crs" method of geopandas. If you want to see the native CRS of your shapefile, use "print(map_.crs)"

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Unfortunately the problem persist even if I remove that line.

Comment: @Jon With to_crs I solved the problem. I thought it was "in place" so I did not reassign the map... Thank you.